# getView() method of ArrayAdapter repeats last item and copy to the first item

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, textwatcher

I have a listview of EditText , they visualize three at a time and then scroll . the problem is that when I scroll down my first EditText fills the last , I can not understand what has gone wrong , can someone help me ?

```
public class EmailListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EmailContactBean> {

private Context mContext;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ListView listView;

private ArrayList<EmailContactBean> emailItem = new ArrayList<EmailContactBean>();



public EmailListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<EmailContactBean> arraylist) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, arraylist);

    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.emailItem = arraylist;


}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.row_email_list, null);
    }



    final EmailContactBean item = emailItem.get(position);


    EditText editText = (EditText) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.email_edit_text);

    editText.setText(item.getName());

    iconForType(item.getType(), editText);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {



            String outputedText = text.toString();
            item.setName(outputedText);



        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public void iconForType(int type, EditText edit) {

    switch (type) {
    case 0:

        edit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                R.drawable.email_personal, 0, 0, 0);

        break;

    case 1:

        edit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.email_home,
                0, 0, 0);

        break;

    case 2:

        edit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                R.drawable.email_works, 0, 0, 0);

        break;
    case 3:

        edit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                R.drawable.email_other, 0, 0, 0);

        break;

    }

}
```

}

I solved it this way:

**EmailListAdapter**

```
public class EmailListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EmailContactBean> {

private Context mContext;
private int layoutResourceId;

private ArrayList<EmailContactBean> emailItem = new ArrayList<EmailContactBean>();

public EmailListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<EmailContactBean> arraylist) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, arraylist);

    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.emailItem = arraylist;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    EmailContactBean ecb = new EmailContactBean();

    ecb = emailItem.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.row_email_list, null);

    }

    EditText editText = (EditText) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.email_edit_text);


    editText.setTag(ecb);


    editText.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(convertView,
            R.id.email_edit_text));

    editText.setText(ecb.getName());

    iconForType(ecb.getType(), editText);


    return convertView;
}

public void iconForType(int type, EditText edit) {

    switch (type) {
    case 0:

        edit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                R.drawable.email_personal, 0, 0, 0);

        break;

    case 1:

        edit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.email_home,
                0, 0, 0);

        break;

    case 2:

        edit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                R.drawable.email_works, 0, 0, 0);

        break;
    case 3:

        edit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                R.drawable.email_other, 0, 0, 0);

        break;

    }

}
```

}

**GenericTextWatcher**

```
public class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private View view;
private int editResource;


public GenericTextWatcher(View view, int editResource) {
    this.view = view;
    this.editResource = editResource;


}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    EditText edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(editResource);

    EmailContactBean ecb = (EmailContactBean) edit.getTag();

    String text = s.toString();

    ecb.setName(text);

}
```

}

Comment: I had trouble with editText and textwatcher within a listview. Seems the listview had problems keeping up with which edittext its listenting to changes for.  I ended up having to check not just the position within getView() but also used getId() of the view and getTag() to make sure I was reading/listening to text changes on the correct edittext.  Try setting the ID or Tag based on something in your list to help differentiate since position will not.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the code in the `afterTextChanged(...)` method of your `TextWatcher`?

Comment: @Squonk you get the point , if comment works well but then I can not update the arraylist.

Comment: @Martin thanks so much , with your help I managed to solve !!!

Comment: it might be bad suggest, but add textwatcher in if (convertView == null) block. according to name of function (addTextChangedListener), multi textwatcher can be added and processed multiple times.

Comment: Good deal. That kicked my butt for a while, so I'm happy to save you some of that trouble :)